# What has the nonaggression principle to do with bitcoin trading?

Tags: transactions, trading, economic-theory

In the Introductory page of the book '*Attack of the 50 foot Blockchain*', the author says (in reference to Ross Ulbricht) :

> A young physics student starts a revolutionary new marketplace based on
>   **the nonaggression principle**, **immune to State coercion**.

What does the author actually mean by that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Book author here! It's because Ulbricht subscribed to the tenets of Anarcho-Capitalism, and founded his drug market as an exercise in ideology. As it happened, the FBI didn't find this a compelling excuse.

Answer (score 0):

I heard of the book, but I don't know it's author, so I can't tell you about his intent. But I can try and translate this into English for you:

> A young physics student starts a revolutionary new marketplace which allows everyone to trade freely and safely without being afraid of Governments coming in an seizing accounts or money because they feel like doing so.

Hope that helps